# How to optimize a Astro component and pass less props?

Tags: astrojs

I am using astro framework for the website which I am contributing. I made an component for it named PostItem.astro. I passed it to some pages. It works well. But the trouble I have is still I am using many codes in my pages like mapping and a lot of props. I need to make the page codes short and include that mapping and all the executions to the component. Also I need to pass very less props to the pages. How could I do it? Please help me.

PostsItem.astro component

```
---
import { Picture } from "astro-imagetools/components";

import Markdown from "@components/Markdown.astro";
import AuthorInfo from "@components/AuthorInfo.astro";

import RecurringImages from "@store/RecurringImages";

const {
  ariaLabel,
  isEven,
  postImgURL,
  altText,
  postLeafWidthMultiplier,
  locale,
  authors,
  createdAt,
  postURL,
  postTitle,
  introText,
  leafVisible,
  greenCupVisible,
  clipPathValue,
} = Astro.props;

const {
  green_cup,
  left_post_leaf,
  green_leaf: right_post_leaf,
} = RecurringImages;
---

<style lang="scss">
  .post-leaf {
    @apply absolute z-20;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  }

  .post-leaf-left {
    @apply -top-[6.5%] left-[3%] sm:-left-[1%] w-[24%] h-auto;
  }

  .post-leaf-right {
    @apply sm:right-0 bottom-[7%] w-[18%] h-auto;

    @media (max-width: 639.98px) {
      @apply -left-[5%] bottom-[6%];
    }
  }
</style>

<div
  role="listitem"
  aria-label={ariaLabel}
  class="link-section grid sm:grid-cols-2 items-center division-gap"
>
  <div
    class:list={[
      "relative post-img-curve-container",
      !isEven && "sm:order-2 ml-auto",
    ]}
  >
    <Picture
      layout="fill"
      src={postImgURL}
      alt={altText}
      sizes={[
        "(min-width: 768px) min(600px, calc(50vw - min(100px, 5vw) - 48px))",
        "(min-width: 640px) min(600px, calc(45vw - 20px))",
        "90vw",
      ].join(", ")}
      attributes={{
        picture: { style: `clip-path: url(${clipPathValue});` },
      }}
    />

    {
      leafVisible && (
        <div
          class:list={[
            "post-leaf",
            isEven ? "post-leaf-left" : "post-leaf-right",
          ]}
        >
          <Picture
            alt=""
            layout="fill"
            placeholder="blurred"
            src={(isEven ? left_post_leaf : right_post_leaf).src}
            sizes={[
              `(min-width: 640px) min(600px, calc((50vw - min(100px, 5vw)) *     ${postLeafWidthMultiplier}))`,
              `calc(90vw * ${postLeafWidthMultiplier})`,
            ].join(", ")}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>

  {/* Text content */}
  <div class:list={["grid division-in-gap", !isEven && "sm:order-1"]}>
    <AuthorInfo
      locale={locale}
      authors={authors}
      createdAt={createdAt}
      color={"black-light"}
    />

    <h2 class="text-h2 text-primary">
      <a class="main-link" href={postURL} set:text={postTitle} />
      {
        greenCupVisible && (
          <span class="icon heading-inline-icon ml-2">
            <img class="w-full h-full" {...green_cup} />
          </span>
        ) 
      }
    </h2>
    <div class="post-intro intro-text">
      <Markdown>{introText}</Markdown>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Posts.astro page

```
---
import Pagination from "@components/Pagination.astro";
import HeroContent from "@components/HeroContent.astro";
import ClipPathSVG from "@components/ClipPathSVG.astro";
import PostItem from "@components/PostItem.astro";

type Post = {
  Estate_name: string;
  authors: any;
  locale: string | undefined;
  updatedAt: string;
  createdAt: string;
  publishedAt: string;
  Intro_text: string;
  Intro_blob: any;
  Block_text: string;
  Category: any | undefined;
  Cooking_part: any;
  Cuisine: any;
  Nutrition_yield: any;
  Recipe_variations: any;
  Title: String;
  Time_preparation: any | undefined;
  Time_text: any | undefined;
  Time_cooking: any;
  Relevant_recipes: any;
  Meta: any;
  localizations: { data: { attributes: Post }[] };
} & Record<string, any>;

interface Props {
  page: {
    posts: Post[];
  } & Record<string, any>;
  ariaLabelRecurData: Record<string, any>;
}

const { page, ariaLabelRecurData } = Astro.props,
  { posts, pagination } = page,
  { STRAPI_URL } = import.meta.env;

posts.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(a.createdAt).getTime();
});

const [firstPost] = posts;
---

<HeroContent
  page={{
    ...page,
    Title: firstPost.Title,
    Intro_text: firstPost.Intro_text,
    authors: firstPost.authors,
    Intro_blob: firstPost.Intro_blob,
    createdAt: firstPost.createdAt,
  }}
  link={firstPost.Meta.URL_slug}
  noAuthorImg={true}
/>

{/* All Posts Section */}
<section class="wrapper grid section-gap section-in-v-pad">
  <div>
    <ClipPathSVG
      id="post-img-curve"
      path="M.516.008C.359.008.1-.008.039.083S.002.495.017.736.182 1 .528 1C.813 1     .902.936.974.717 1 .624 1 .395.946.128.897-.045.735.008.516.008"
/>

    <div
      role="list"
      aria-label={ariaLabelRecurData.All_posts_text}
      class="grid section-gap"
    >
      {
        posts.slice(1).map((post, index) => {
          const isEven = index % 2 === 0,
            postImgURL = STRAPI_URL + post.Intro_blob.data.attributes.url,
            postLeafWidthMultiplier = isEven ? 0.24 : 0.18;

          return (
            <PostItem
              ariaLabel={`${ariaLabelRecurData.Post_text + (index + 2)}     ${ariaLabelRecurData.Product_post_of_text} ${posts.length}`}
              postImgURL={postImgURL}
              altText={post.Intro_blob.data.attributes.alternativeText}
              locale={page.locale}
              authors={post.authors}
              createdAt={post.createdAt}
              postURL={`/` + post.Meta.URL_slug}
              postTitle={post.Title}
              introText={post.Intro_text}
              isEven={isEven}
              postLeafWidthMultiplier={postLeafWidthMultiplier}
              leafVisible={true}
              greenCupVisible={true}
              clipPathValue={"#post-img-curve"}
            />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  </div>

  {pagination && <Pagination pagination={pagination} />}
</section>


Estate.astro

---
import Markdown from "@components/Markdown.astro";
import ClipPathSVG from "@components/ClipPathSVG.astro";
import ClippedPicture from "@components/ClippedPicture.astro";
import KindnessImpact from "@components/KindnessImpact.astro";
import EstatesInfoSection from "@components/EstatesInfoSection.astro";
import PostItem from "@components/PostItem.astro";

import SecondaryPageLayout from "@layouts/SecondaryPageLayout.astro";

import RecurringImages from "@store/RecurringImages";

const { left_quote } = RecurringImages;

const { page } = Astro.props,
  { posts, locale, blogs } = page,
  { STRAPI_URL } = import.meta.env;

const relatedPosts = blogs?.data?.map(({ attributes }) => attributes);
---

<style lang="scss">
  .estate-quote-container {
    clip-path: url(#quote-bg-curve);

    @media (max-width: 639.98px) {
      clip-path: url(#quote-bg-curve-sm);
    }
  }

  .quote-img-container {
    aspect-ratio: 6 / 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 375px;
  }

  .estate-quote {
    padding: 0 clamp(2.188rem, 3.3vw + 0.8rem, 3.75rem);
  }

  .estate-quote-icon {
    height: clamp(1.563rem, 2.2vw + 0.15rem, 2.188rem);
  }
</style>
 <SecondaryPageLayout {page} {relatedPosts} plainTitle={true}>
  <div role="main" class="grid section-gap section-in-v-pad">
    <div
      class="wrapper flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center division-gap"
    >
      <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
        <h2 class="text-h2 text-primary">
          {page.Heading_block}
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div class="intro-text">
        <Markdown>{page.Block_text}</Markdown>
      </div>
    </div>

    {/* All Estates Section */}
    <div id="estates" class="wrapper">
     <ClipPathSVG
        id="estate-img-curve"
        path="M.516.008C.359.008.1-.008.039.083S.002.495.017.736.182 1 .528 1C.813 1    .902.936.974.717 1 .624 1 .395.946.128.897-.045.735.008.516.008"
      />

      <div
        role="list"
        aria-label={page.Aria_label_all_estates_text}
        class="grid section-gap"
      >
        {
          posts.map((estate, index) => {
            const isEven = index % 2 === 0;

            return (
              <PostItem
                postImgURL={STRAPI_URL + estate.Intro_blob.data.attributes.url}
                altText={estate.Intro_blob.data.attributes.alternativeText}
                clipPathValue={"#estate-img-curve"}
                postURL={`/` + estate.Meta.URL_slug}
                postTitle={estate.Estate_name}
                introText={estate.Intro_text}
                isEven={isEven}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div
        aria-label={page.Block2_aria_label_text}
        class="estate-quote-container blob-div-in-pad bg-primary w-full h-full"
      >
        <ClipPathSVG
          id="quote-bg-curve"
          path="M0.04,0.087 C0.086,-0.001,0.164,0.007,0.262,0.002   C0.427,-0.005,0.522,0.007,0.687,0.002 c0.115,-0.003,0.179,0,0.242,0.029 c0.048,0.022,0.075,0.301,0.071,0.479 c-0.003,0.162,0.008,0.386,-0.054,0.413 c-0.058,0.025,-0.193,0.034,-0.252,0.049 c-0.111,0.03,-0.23,-0.006,-0.332,0 c-0.092,0.006,-0.206,0.08,-0.309,-0.049 C0,0.856,-0.001,0.685,0,0.511 C0.002,0.345,-0.007,0.177,0.04,0.087"
        />

        <ClipPathSVG
          id="quote-bg-curve-sm"
          path="M0.913,0.04 c0.088,0.046,0.08,0.124,0.084,0.222 c0.007,0.165,-0.005,0.26,0,0.425 c0.003,0.116,0,0.179,-0.029,0.242 c-0.022,0.048,-0.301,0.075,-0.479,0.071 c-0.162,-0.003,-0.386,0.008,-0.413,-0.054 C0.05,0.888,0.042,0.753,0.026,0.694 C-0.003,0.583,0.033,0.464,0.026,0.363 C0.021,0.271,-0.054,0.156,0.076,0.054 C0.144,0,0.315,-0.001,0.489,0 C0.655,0.002,0.823,-0.007,0.913,0.04"
        />

        <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full gap-y-6 items-center relative z-20">
          {/* Quote Image */}
          <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2">
            <div class="quote-img-container mx-auto sm:ml-0">
              <ClippedPicture
                id="quote-img-curve"
                alt={page.Block2_blob.data.attributes.alternativeText}
                src={STRAPI_URL + page.Block2_blob.data.attributes.url}
                path="M0.516,0.008 C0.36,0.008,0.1,-0.008,0.04,0.082    S0.002,0.495,0.017,0.736 S0.182,1,0.528,1 c0.285,0,0.374,-0.064,0.446,-0.283 c0.031,-0.093,0.047,-0.322,-0.029,-0.59 C0.896,-0.045,0.735,0.008,0.516,0.008"
                sizes={[
                  "(min-width: 640px) min(450px, calc(50vw - min(100px, 5vw) - clamp(23px,    3.875vw, 50px)))",
                  "calc(90vw - clamp(23px, 3.875vw, 50px))",
                ].join(", ")}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* Text content */}
          <div class="w-full sm:w-1/2 h-full">
            <div class="flex flex-wrap px-2.5 sm:px-0 xl:-ml-6">
              <div class="estate-quote-icon">
                <img class="w-full h-full" {...left_quote} />
              </div>

              <div
                class="estate-quote text-b3 max-w-none font-bold text-secondary prose"
              >
                {page.Block2_text}
              </div>

              <div class="estate-quote-icon mr-[25px] ml-auto rotate-180">
                <img class="w-full h-full" {...left_quote} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <EstatesInfoSection page={page} />

    <KindnessImpact
      {locale}
      heading={page.Block4_heading}
      impacts={page.Impacts}
    />
  </div>
</SecondaryPageLayout>
```

I tried many ways to solve it. But it was not successful. Any solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why do you need to pass "less props" and what do you mean by that? Please only include relevant code, and do provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example